# Autofill fields in a subform of access2003 based on a previous entry/field

Tags: forms, ms-access-2003, autofill, auto-populate, subforms

First off, I am new at this.  Secondly, yes I am working with access 2003 and this is not by choice.  It is the program that my job has provided to me, so I am stuck using it.

Question: I have created a form with a subform in access2003.  The form has three fields: State, Year and CompanyName.

The sub form then lists three fields: CompanyID, Date, and AmtPaid (in dollars).

I would like for the subform to autopopulate/autofill in the CompanyID in the subform each time I have users enter a new line of data in to the subform.

For example: I choose the following in the form...State=PA, Year=2017, CompanyName=ABC (ID=2).
I then can enter values in to my subform...CompanyID=2, Date=3/1/17, AmtPaid=$10.00.
When I go to enter a new line of data, for example the amount paid for the same company on 4/1/17, I would like for the CompanyID to automatically fill in "2".  My goal is for this field to autofill for each company ID since I am planning on avoiding user error and also planning on hiding this field.

I understand the default assignment in the properties window of the field, but if i enter in the number "2", then "2" will be entered by default for all companys, not just for company ABC.  I believe i have to write some sort of code that references a previous field or the first field in the subform, so that the new line copies what has been entered previously.

Any help is much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Check out master fields and child fields. Consider various main records for each company. Do not forget that you can have a master fields as a control. Also do not forget that you can rewrite default values in code.

Comment: BTW you will never avoid user error, you can only cut down on it.